# Why FormView not saving data within a DetailView?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, formview, detailview

I have a DetailView Based on a model ( A ) and on the same template I have a ModelFormView from a  model B which has FK to model (A)

The data from form doesn't get saved to the database.

This is the **DetailView**:

```
class LocationView(DetailView):

    template_name = "base/stocks/location.html"
    model = LocationStock

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

         context = super(LocationView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['form'] = OutsModelForm
         return context

    def get_object(self):

         id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
         return get_object_or_404(LocationStock, id=id_)
```

This is the **FormView**:

```
  class OutsAdd(FormView):

       form_class = OutsModelForm
       success_url = reverse_lazy('base:dashboard')

       def form_valid(self, form):

           return super().form_valid(form)
```

This is the **url.py**:

```
    path('locations/<int:id>', LocationView.as_view(), name='location-detail'),
    path('locations/outs', require_POST(OutsAdd.as_view()), name='outs-add'),
```

This is the **template**:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'outs-add' %}" >

<div class="modal-content">
        {% csrf_token %} 
          {% render_field form.quantity placeholder="Quantity"%}
          {% render_field form.id_year placeholder="Year"%}
          {% render_field form.id_location placeholder="ID Location"%}

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <input class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" type="submit" value="Save">
  </div>
</form>
```

The data gets POSTED in the /locations/outs but is not saving to the actual database.How can I save it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality of Django's `FormView` is really only meant to display a form on a GET request, show form errors in the case of `form_invalid`, and redirect to a new URL if the form is valid. In order to persist the data to the database you have two options. First you can simply call `form.save()` in your `FormView`:

```
class OutsAdd(FormView):
    form_class = OutsModelForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('base:dashboard')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Or, you can use the generic `CreateView`. Django's `CreateView` is similar to a `FormView` except it assumes it's working with a `ModelForm` and calls `form.save()` for you behind the scenes.

Comment: @titpoettt did this answer help you out? Is there anything else I can expand upon further?